# Не отображает отрывок кода

Tags: javascript

Я делаю календарь, все работает, если удалить else. Когда я ставлю else, ничего не отображает, подскажите, как это исправить и из-за чего это все?

```
function printDate() {
    if (months[theDate.getMonth() + 1] == "data_image/feb.gif") {
        switch (days[theDate.getDate()]) {
        case "data_image/14th.gif":
            {
                document.write('<img src="' + Happy[1] + '">');
                document.write('<img src="' + days[14] + '">'); // day
            }
            break
        case "data_image/23th.gif":
            {
                document.write('<img src="' + Happy[2] + '">');
                document.write('<img src="' + days[14] + '">'); // day
            }
            break
        default:
            {
                document.write('<img src="' + months[theDate.getMonth() + 1] + '">'); // month
                document.write('<br>');
                document.write('<img src="' + days[theDate.getDate()] + '">');
            } // day
        }
    }
}
else
{
    document.write('<img src="' + months[theDate.getMonth() + 1] + '">'); // month
    document.write('<br>');
    document.write('<img src="' + days[theDate.getDate()] + '">');
} // day
}
```

Comment: думаю, лишняя фигурная скобка перед `//day` мешает достичь нужного результата)

Comment: я скобку убрал, несколько рас проверил но ничего не меняется, результата по прежнему нету.
Я думаю что возможно что-то связано с theDate.getMonth и theDate.getDate() но вот что..?

Comment: внимательно просмотрев Ваш код, могу предположить, что перед `else` лишняя фигурная скобка и после `break` не хватате точек с запятой.

Comment: извини, LeD4eG, просто закладка долго висела в браузере

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в следующем: необходимо следить за фигурными скобками и точками с запятой в своём коде. Вас интересовало почему так происходило? Попробую объяснить.

У Вас поставлена лишняя закрывающая фигурная скобка перед ветвью `else`. Вроде, ошибка "несерьёзная" - подумаешь!скобка!
Но получается следующее. Фигурная закрывающая скобка означает окончание блока. Теперь (для простоты понимания) посчитаем количество, открытых Вами блоков: открываем функцию (`function`), открываем условную ветвь (`if`), открываем переключатель (`switch`) - итого 3. а теперь переместимся в конец этого блока и посчитаем сколько Вы закрываете блоков - 4...получается Вы закрыли переключатель, блок условия и....саму функцию....затем, неожиданно появляется блок `else` - что просто ставит в тупик интерпретатор `javascript`. Именно поэтому при удалении блока `else` у Вас всё работало - потому что фукнция закрыта...вроде всё прописано...но у Вас есть ещё одна ошибка!

Оба прерывания (`break`) указаны без точек с запятой. Но эта ошибка "уходила" из-под внимания отладчика, потому что это банальная ошибка исключается самим интерпретатором. Но это **не повод**, чтобы не следить за их правильной расстановкой.

Так что, просто следите за тем, что пишите, используйте табуляцию. Почитайте пару статей, как оформлять свой код, чтобы свести подобные ошибки к нулю. Я уверен, у Вас всё это получится!))удачи!)